# EditText in a Listview

Tags: android

I'm writing a custom listview and I've put a EditText and textViews. The issue is focus on the list doesn't work. When i touch the EditText, the softkeyboard appears but EditText loses focus. When I touch it again the softkeyboard changes and I'm able to write in the EditText after pressing 'done'. EditText is cleared. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Please cuold you attach your code, it is more simpleir to help you if you show your code.

Comment: ok but what exactly do you mean? the xml or the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MIGHT just be a stupid thing i'm saying here, but you could try the following: place an `OnClickListener` on the `ListView` items. If you click on an item in the list, and that item is an `EditText`, then use "requestFocus()" method to focus it.

I'm thinking, but i might be wrong, that both the `EditText` and `ListView` item (row) are requesting focus when you click on them, and `ListView` probably "wins" :) But this is just a guess, I might be wrong.

```
    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView)).setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {              
                   /* Here, check to see if the item clicked is the EditText or whatever.
                    * If so, then set focus to it */
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well i just found something out.I added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" on the manifest and it seems to work.Although what my problem is now is that whenever i'm done writing on the textField instead of a 'done' in the softKeyboard i get 'next' button.Any idea how i can change that?

Comment: Try adding android:imeOptions="actionDone" to your EditTExt or via code: yourEditTExt.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

Comment: sorry for tiring you.Do you happen to know how can i put a 'done' on softkeyboard for a multiLine textField?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Uhm, no, THAT I don't know, sorry.

Comment: ooh it's okay i figured it out i just put android:imeOptions="actionDone" on the xml of the editText .I just post it just in case.Thanks for replying